# Cmder hangs seriously on pressing Ctrl-C

Tags: windows-10, cmder

I am unable to use `Cmder` because it behaves badly on pressing Ctrl-C.

Most of the times it just prints `^C`

[image]

But if you try to break some program at unlucky moment, it hangs displaying "Not responding" at window title

[image]

If you force window to close, it still won't close but redraw it with larger font

[image]

requiring you to close window again.

This leads `Cmder` to become useless. Because Ctrl-C is rather often keystroke. On each Ctrl-C you have a big chance to be required to kill `Cmder` window hard, with dozens of seconds waiting, pressing multiple keys, restarting `cmder` and loosing entered information.

Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599822/command-prompt-gets-stuck-and-continues-on-enter-key-press    .....  Does this help?

Comment: "Is it possible to fix it?" – The answer is either "yes" or "no", I guess; not very educative. "Why does it happen?" and/or "how can we fix it?" are way better questions. *Maybe* you wanted to ask one of these. A good answer will *probably* assume (at least) one of these, but IMO being precise and explicit in the question is a virtue nevertheless. Consider changing the question. Or is "is it possible to fix it?" really *the* question. If so, it's a poor one.